# Prettyprint json in java until only the first nest

Tags: java, json, gson, pretty-print

I have a json of the form:

`{"John": {"company": "xxx", "address": "San Francisco", "contact": ["phone1", "phone2"]}, "Alice": {"company": "yyy", "address": "Boston", "contact": ["phone3", "phone4"]}}`

If I use GsonBuilder setPrettyPrinting, it is printing it as:

```
{
  "John": {
    "company": "xxx",
    "address": "San Francisco",
    "contact": [
      "phone1",
      "phone2"
    ]
  },
  "Alice": {
    "company": "yyy",
    "address": "Boston",
    "contact": [
      "phone3",
      "phone4"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to print it as following:

```
{
  "John": {"company": "xxx", "address": "San Francisco", "contact": ["phone1", "phone2"]}, 
  "Alice": {"company": "yyy", "address": "Boston", "contact": ["phone3", "phone4"]}
}
```

OR at least have the list of contacts in one line

```
{
  "John": {
    "company": "xxx",
    "address": "San Francisco",
    "contact": ["phone1", "phone2"]
  },
  "Alice": {
    "company": "yyy",
    "address": "Boston",
    "contact": ["phone3", "phone4"]
  }
}
```

Is this possible? Can this be done using the GsonBuilder module?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is no. GsonBuilder doesn't have that functionality.
But you can write custom java code to pretty print first level of the JSON alone
By getting the keys and looping the first level alone.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Sort of. Gson provides indentations for entire documents, and having the indentation configured only affects on whether JSON elements are put on new line with a configured indentation level or not.

> Can this be done using the GsonBuilder module?

No. The `GsonBuilder` is clear on it in its JavaDoc and provides little configurability: with it, you can only enable or disable indentation, and of course it cannot handle sophisticated cases itself.

However, you can extend `JsonWriter` to handle nesting yourself and switch the indents depending on your current nesting level.

```java
public final class PrettyJsonWriter
        extends JsonWriter {

    private int level;

    public PrettyJsonWriter(final Writer out) {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWriter beginArray()
            throws IOException {
        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = super.beginArray();
        level++;
        adjustIndent();
        return jsonWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWriter endArray()
            throws IOException {
        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = super.endArray();
        level--;
        adjustIndent();
        return jsonWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWriter beginObject()
            throws IOException {
        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = super.beginObject();
        level++;
        adjustIndent();
        return jsonWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonWriter endObject()
            throws IOException {
        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = super.endObject();
        level--;
        adjustIndent();
        return jsonWriter;
    }

    // handle whatever rules you want
    private void adjustIndent() {
        final String indent;
        switch ( level ) {
        case 1:
            indent = "\t";
            break;
        default:
            indent = StringUtils.EMPTY;
            break;
        }
        setIndent(indent);
    }

}
```

The usage is trivial:

```java
final JsonWriter prettyJsonWriter = new PrettyJsonWriter(...);
...
gson.toJson(jsonElement, prettyJsonWriter);
```

Your document would be printed like this:

```json
{
    "John": {"company":"xxx","address":"San Francisco","contact":["phone1","phone2"]},
    "Alice": {"company":"yyy","address":"Boston","contact":["phone3","phone4"]}
}
```

Note that it **cannot** add "pretty spaces" for inline elements (i.e., `John`'s and `Alice`'s properties are delimited with `,`, and not `,`  (trailing space)).